# What is "invalidation" in this Observablehq example?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise, observablehq

https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-lattice?collection=@d3/d3-drag

there is a line

`invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());`

what is this invalidation?  by the console.log, it is a promise, but I don't see it defined anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observablehq loads the [standard library](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib/blob/master/README.md#invalidation), which provides the [`invalidation`](https://github.com/observablehq/stdlib/blob/master/README.md#invalidation) method. According to the documentation, `invalidation` is...

> A promise that resolves when the current cell is re-evaluated: when the cell’s code changes, when it is run using Shift-Enter, or when a referenced input changes.

This notebook explains it in details: https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/invalidation